# How to log into router with HttpWebRequest?

Tags: vb.net, authentication, httpwebrequest, router

I'm trying to figure out how to successfully log into a DSL-Router (Model: Speedport w504v Type A).
I wrote a function usinig HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse. So far this function is not finished and is only for finding out the right login process.

```
Public Function DoRequest(ByVal url As String, ByVal password As String, ByVal container As CookieContainer) As String

    'Login Request
    Dim reqLogin As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create("https://speedport.ip/cgi-bin/login.cgi"), HttpWebRequest)
    reqLogin.CookieContainer = container
    reqLogin.Method = "POST"
    reqLogin.Referer = "https://speedport.ip/hcti_start_passwort.stm"
    reqLogin.KeepAlive = True
    reqLogin.Host = "speedport.ip"
    reqLogin.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    reqLogin.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
    reqLogin.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3")
    reqLogin.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")

    'Login Data
    Dim encoding As New ASCIIEncoding()
    Dim data As String = Uri.EscapeDataString("pws") & "=" & Uri.EscapeDataString(password)
    Dim bytes As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(data)
    reqLogin.ContentLength = bytes.Length
    Dim stream As Stream = reqLogin.GetRequestStream
    stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
    stream.Close()

    'Login Response
    Dim resLogin As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(reqLogin.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

    'Receive Cookie
    Dim CookieHeaderValue As String = reqLogin.Headers.Get("Cookie")
    If CookieHeaderValue <> Nothing Then
        Dim aCookie As String() = CookieHeaderValue.Split("=")
        Dim Cookie As New Cookie
        Cookie.Domain = "speedport.ip"
        Cookie.Path = "/"
        Cookie.Secure = True
        Cookie.Name = aCookie(0)
        Cookie.Value = aCookie(1)
        container.Add(Cookie)
    End If

    'Url Request
    Dim reqIndex As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
    reqIndex.CookieContainer = container
    reqIndex.Method = "GET"
    reqIndex.Referer = "https://speedport.ip/wait_login.stm"
    reqIndex.KeepAlive = True
    reqIndex.Host = "speedport.ip"
    reqIndex.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"

    'Url Content
    Dim resIndex As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(reqIndex.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(resIndex.GetResponseStream())
    Dim output As String = sr.ReadToEnd
    resIndex.Close()

    Return output
End Function
```

Unfortunately I don't get the right content. Instead I'm getting the sitecontent from an Error-Page saying:

> double administration access!

This site is returned when you try to login but there is another session already running.
So maybe I'm already successfully logged in but don't get the site content.

I get the header information from an Firefox AddOn called HTTP Live Header.
I also tried to run curl but also did not work:

```
curl -d "pws=PASSWORD" -c cookies.txt -e https://speedport.ip/hcti_start_passwort.stm -k https://speedport.ip/cgi-bin/login.cgi
curl -c cookies.txt -e https://speedport.ip/wait_login.stm -k https://speedport.ip/index.stm
```

Maybe someone has an idea what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Using Fiddler I figured it out. I've to set also the User Agent Header for the first request.

```
reqLogin.UserAgent = "YOUR USERAGNET STRING"
```

Furthermore I don't have to get the value for `reqLogin.Headers.Get("Cookie")`.
It's already set to the CookieContainer so cancel the "Receive Cookie" part.